# Delete Query in Mysql using a TOP Clause?

Tags: mysql

I am having a tough time writing a query to delete the Top 2 entries repeated in Mysql.Can somebody please help me in this.I have come across how to query for select statement but not for delete query.Following is the requirement ;If the table contains more or equal to 10 values of a particular record the delete the first record(topmost).Following is my code.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM billinfo WHERE tableno='10'") or die(mysql_error());

   $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
    echo  $num_rows;

    $query2='';
   if($num_rows>10)
   {

        $query2 = mysql_query("DELETE * TOP FROM  billinfo Where tableno='10')");
   }
```

Comment: As a sidenote, mysql functions are deprecated and you should use mysqli or PDO instead. http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you're checking if `$num_rows` is less than 10, if I understand correctly you want the opposite case.

You have not defined what you mean by "top" -- I assume the largest value of a field, and hence I've written it as `XX` in the query.

Try something like

```
if($num_rows>10) {
   $query2 = mysql_query("DELETE FROM billinfo WHERE tableno='10' ORDER BY XX DESC LIMIT 1");
}
```

This will delete 1 row ( defined in the `LIMIT` part ), and since the result set is ordered by `XX DESC` that will be the row that has the largest `XX` value.

For more see Mysql documentation on [delete](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html)

Comment: Thnx hexblot.How carelessly i pasted the code.Edited the question now.THnx again.